# Split first name and last name with php and search in array

Tags: php, string, split, strpos

I have a problem. I have a List of thousand names and must split them with php, perhaps with mysql. The Names looks like this:

```
johndoe
peterhoward
martinsmith
mickymaus
aaaa
```

I have an list of all possible and valid first names and lastnames. Now I want to check first in my list of firstnames (mysql table first_names) if the first name. Then I want to remove the firstname of the string and want to check if the last name is valie (mysql table last_name). But at the moment I have no idea to do that.

Comment: Can you show us some code you've written to attempt this?

Comment: that's crazy to start with, why do you have a list with out any separation?

Comment: It was an Backup from an old database and the admin forgot to insert a seperator...

Comment: I have also the problem to find a start... have no code till yet.

Comment: I'm not going to code it for you, but try `foreach`, `strpos` to get first char, if `in_array` firstNames, `strpos` to check remaining chars, if `in_array` lastNames then it's your first and last name, else `strpos` to get first 2 chars, ... , else `strpos` to get first 3 chars, else ... What a mess!!

Comment: ...You have a list of possible first names, and last names, but they're they're all on different rows? How did this even happen in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

**1. PHP Method:**

Check out the [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) library function in PHP.  This is the most commonly-used and straightforward method in PHP to see if one string is contained in another string.  So pull your data set of first names from SQL and compare them in PHP.

```
 if ( strpos($FullName, $FirstName) !== false ) ...
```

**2. SQL Method:**

The [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator in SQL will compare 2 values to see if one is contained in the other.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE FullName LIKE FirstName + '%';
```